# How to automake installation process on Linux-like operating systems?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, installation

I wrote a simple C application but it has some dependencies. Instead of giving my friend (who is a linux noob) commands to run in terminal, to install the dependencies, I would like to give him a single file that would install everything my application needs.

Btw, is makefile a good idea, or maybe a bash script would be most appropriate? I would like to ask about the root password only once, save it somewhere (in the script/makefile variable) and then simply use it to install all dependencies. Any ideas how to do it the most professional way?

Answer (score 2):

This is what packages are for.

Depending on what target OS/distribution, you will need to package a DEB or an RPM.

[There are tools](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to simplify this process that allow declaring dependencies as well as running pre/post install/uninstall scripts.

The most professional way to distribute this is using a private repository.

Comment: Ok, used `fpm` it seems it worked but I dont know where to find installed application and how to check if it is actually installed or not? I had no errors during the building/installing with `dpkg -i mypackage.deb`

Comment: `dpkg -L $package` will tell where you have installed it. Note that all this can be customized.